# Ring properties which can be checked on sufficiently many Ore localizations

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, localization

Let $R$ be a non-commutative Ore domain, and let $R[S_i^{-1}]$ be a finite set of Ore localizations.  The absence of a geometric theory means there is no obvious candidate for when this set of localizations is a `cover' (correct me if I am wrong on this).
A weaker requirement is that
$$ \bigcap_i R[S_i^{-1}] = R,$$
where the intersection is in the skew-field of fractions of $R$.

**Question:** Assume that $R$ is an intersection of finitely-many Ore localizations $R[S_i^{-1}]$. What ring-theoretic properties of $R$ can be checked on the $R[S_i^{-1}]$?

That is, I am looking for properties $P$ such that, if each $R[S_i^{-1}]$ has property $P$, then $R$ also has property $P$.

Examples of properties I have in mind:

- Finitely-generated
- Noetherian
- Cohen-Macaulay

Properties I can show can be checked on the localizations:

- There are no nontrivial module-finite extension rings contained in the skew-field of fractions. (I don't know the name of this, but in the commutative case, it is one definition of an **integrally-closed** domain).

Comment: A reasonable replacement for covers is that the product of your localizations be faithfully flat over $R$. This condition is quite useful.

Comment: To supplement Mariano's comment, one could also demand that $\mathrm{Mod}(R_i) \to \mathrm{Mod}(R)$ defines a cover in the sense of Rosenberg's non-commutative algebraic geometry. Perhaps some properties are already mentioned in his work, you should check it.

Comment: I don't do much noncommutative stuff, but it seems to me that an obvious replacement for covers is that the "Cech complex" `$0 \to R \to \bigoplus R[S_i^{-1}] \to \bigoplus R[S_i^{-1}, S_j^{-1}] \to \bigoplus R[S_i^{-1}, S_j^{-1}, S_k^{-1}] \to \cdots$` be exact.